# Android Live wallpaper - onOffsetsChanged

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Is there a better way to move the bitmap inside a canvas without redrawingBitmap every time, for every single one?

```
public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {


             final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();                                                   
             Canvas c = null;
             try {
                  c = holder.lockCanvas();
                  if (c != null) {                                  
                            c.drawBitmap(this.ImageI, xPixels, 0, null);                                                                    
                            c.drawBitmap(this.ImageII, xPixels, 0, paint);  



                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking: is there a better way?
The answer is: no.  You need to redraw your whole scene, background and all, every frame.
Also, generally speaking, you don't want to draw in onOffsetsChanged; just update variables that you're using in your runnable.  Take a look at how the Cube example in the SDK works.  Joey's example is correct, too.  Hope this helps

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much! Witch of these you think would be better to call onOffsetChanged? drawFrame(); or mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawWall, 30); ?? i really don't like the framerate.

Comment: @Misca You don't need to put any drawing calls in onOffsetsChanged (the call to drawFrame() in the Cube example is actually superfluous).  The next "scheduled" call of your runnable will "automatically" start using the values that you've changed in your shared variables.  Set the framerate of your choice in the body of the runnable, where it schedules subsequent calls to itself.

Comment: well yes but in my thread i use a 10 seconds schedule. Should i schedule for 30 milis in the onOffsetChanged?

Comment: @Misca Good point...if your thread is on a slow schedule, yes, you will want to force a rapid processing of your offset change.  I would call the runnable directly (as in the Cube example), though a postDelayed with delay=0 should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like I usually do in a situation where you are reading and modifying a location or image via the offsets changing.  I use onOffsetsChanged to feed information to a constant variable that is updated in my draw routine automatically as it changes.

Start by defining the constants you want to work with like so...

```
Private float mXOffset = 0,
              mYOffset = 0,
              mXStep   = 0,
              mYStep   = 0,
              mXPixels = 0,
              mYPixels = 0;
```

In this example I am capturing all of the values from the onOffsetsChanged event, you need only define and capture the offsets, steps, or pixels you will be using.

```
public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {

mXOffset = xOffset;
mYOffset = yOffset;
mXStep   = xStep;
mYStep   = yStep;
mXPixels = xPixels;
mYPixels = yPixels; 

DrawStuff();   
}
```

Once you have this data it will give you a little more power and flexibility to use in your application.  You can call your canvas updates now like the following and when the offsets change each time your draw routine is called you can use these numbers to modify location of image, speed of movement, or any other mathematical calculation you would like.

```
private void DrawStuff(){
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();                                                   
             Canvas c = null;
             try {
                  c = holder.lockCanvas();
                  if (c != null) {                                  
                      c.drawBitmap(this.ImageI, mXPixels,mYPixels + mYOffset,null);                                                                    
                      c.drawBitmap(this.ImageII, xPixels, 0, paint);  
                                 }
                 } finally {
                    if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }

    }
```

and so on and so forth.  Hope this is what you was asking I wasn't entirely clear. This will also give you the ability to use these offsets, steps, and locations elsewhere if you have a need.

Comment: Isn't there a better way to translate the image on the screen without reloading the bitmaps and redraw them? My thread is running every minute and in the draw i do lot of stuff.  Thank you :)

Comment: in the code you provided you are not actually loading in the bitmaps you are just referencing the bitmaps that you loaded in else where.  By using c.drawBitmap you are just applying said bitmap to the canvas.  So with that being said depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish you should be able to manipulate these images pretty easily without worrying too much about the processor.  If you are calling different images often then possibly a small array to handle the bitmaps you will be working with.